Differentiability implies continuity of $f(x,y)$
I have seen proofs of this statement on the site however none use the definition of differentiability I am familiar with which is why I'm asking this question. My proof is as follows:
If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ then: $$f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) = A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0) + \alpha(x,y)(x-x_0) + \beta(x,y)(y-y_0)$$ where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are functions such that $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)}\alpha(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)} \beta(x,y) = 0$. From here we can take the limit:$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)}f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0) =\\\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)} (A+\alpha(x,y))(x-x_0) + (B+\beta(x,y))(y-y_0) =\\ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)} A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0) = 0$$
Is this proof correct?

Yes, your proof is correct. Though for what it's worth, here's an important thought to keep in mind...

It is good habit to be a little more specific when defining mathematical objects. For instance, what is the domain of $\alpha,\beta?$ What is the range? Do these functions satisfy differentiable continuity? (Answer: They do...but over what region?) It certainly is good to get into the habit of being a little more specific here, especially when it may lead to confusion.

For Instance... Consider arbitrary function $f:X\to Y$ where $X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}^2.$ Assume $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0).$ Then there must exist constants $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ and differentiably continuous functions $\alpha,\beta:X\to Y$ (where $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)}\alpha(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)} \beta(x,y) = 0)$ such that: $f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) = A(x-x_0) + B(y-y_0) + \alpha(x,y)(x-x_0) + \beta(x,y)(y-y_0).$ From here, it immediately must follow that: (finish proof just as you did).

Thank you! And yes I agree that I do need to be more precise with the definitions of the functions. I have one question and that is what is meant by differentiable continuity? Does it mean that the partial derivatives of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are continuous in $X$?

@Moxy We say that functions $\alpha,\beta$ are differentiable continuous over $X$ if they each have continuous derivative over $X.$ And this is true if and only if $\alpha, \beta$ have continuous partial derivatives over $X$ (if I’m remembering correctly).
